# I get 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command when I run "npx react-native init AwesomeProject"

Tags: npm, react-native

I have installed node and jdk8 using chocolaty.

While I was following the official guide *"Setting up the development environment -> React Native ClI Quick start for 'Windows & Android'"* I get the following error when I run `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` command:

```
'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\UOG\React_Native_Projects\MyFirstApp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native init AwesomeProject

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muhammad Suleman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-23T09_10_07_360Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

**npm install -g react-native-cli**

after that just add your npm path to your system variables in environment variables

**C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm**

Comment: But the documentation says that react-native-cli may cause unexpected issues.

Comment: If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.

**npx react-native init [project name]** just tried this, @JhonasBoeno

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. It got fixed by first typing following command:

```js
npm i react-native
```

then:

```js
yarn react-native init AwesomeProject
```

and it worked!!

[image: Following is the screenshot of it]